# How to rotate an image in js canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am currently working on a project with a friend in which we need to draw out a picture on a canvas with a specific rotation.

I have searched for it on google and I have found several solutions that should work, but when I try to use the solution it doesn't work for me.

This is the code for drawing the rotated image that we have at the moment:

```
export function drawImage(src, sizeX, sizeY, x, y, rotation, ctx) {
    let img = new Image(sizeX, sizeY);
    img.src = src;

    // Save the rotation and translation
    ctx.save();

    // Draw the rotated image
    ctx.translate(x, y);
    ctx.rotate((rotation * Math.PI) / 180);
    ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);

    // Restore the rotation and translation
    ctx.restore();
};
```

It does not give any error when ran, but it doesn't rotate the image either. It just draws the image on the given coordinates without the rotation.

I tried rotating and translating the canvas first, I've tried drawing the picture first and I would have expected for one of them to draw the rotated image but both just drew the image without rotation.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit 1: ctx is the canvas' context
(ctx = canvas:getContext('2d');)

Comment: What is `Image`?  What is `ctx`?  Don't you need to undo the translation after doing the rotation?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not ideal but should draw rotated image. I think problem is in usage or project structure.

Here is working example with your function (fixed a little bit). You can try it out pressing blue button.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const pr = window.devicePixelRatio;
canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth * pr;
canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight * pr;

function drawImage(src, sizeX, sizeY, x, y, rotation, ctx) {
    let img = new Image(sizeX, sizeY);
    img.src = src;

    // Save the rotation and translation
    ctx.save();

    // Draw the rotated image
    ctx.translate(x, y);
    ctx.rotate((rotation * Math.PI) / 180);
    ctx.drawImage(img, -sizeX/2, -sizeY/2, sizeX, sizeY);

    // Restore the rotation and translation
    ctx.restore();
};

const draw = () => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  const phi = (Date.now()/10) % 360;
  drawImage("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/thumb/2/24/Lenna.png/1200px-Lenna.png", 100*pr, 100*pr, 100*pr, 100*pr, phi, ctx);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
};


draw();
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px #999 solid;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```